# Как в Android десериализовать JSON вида https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit2

Как в Android десериализовать JSON вида желательно с помощью Retrofit

```
{
  "message":{
      "affenpinscher":[],
      "african":[],
      "bulldog":["boston","french"],
      ...
      "retriever":["chesapeake","curly","flatcoated","golden"]
      ...
      "wolfhound":["irish"]
    }
}
```

https://api.dog.ceo/breeds/list/all/

Так чтоб можно было создать класс связующий с подклассом

Class Dog(val nameBreed:String, val namesSub:ArrayString)

Class SubBreed(val subNameBreed:String)

Пишу на Kotlin

Comment: совершенно непонятно, что вызывает сложности с одной стороны и что нужно сделать - с другой. Конкретизируйте вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сам Retrofit не занимается десериализацией JSON. Для этого есть GSON или Jackson либо в виде подключаемых конвертеров или совершенно отдельно. Уточните вопрос.